# python script to scan a pdf file using online scanner

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I used this code to scan multiple PDF files contained in a folder with the online scanner "https://wepawet.iseclab.org/" using this scrip.

```
import mechanize
import re
import os

def upload_file(uploaded_file):
    url = "https://wepawet.iseclab.org/"
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False) # ignore robots
    br.open(url)
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    f = os.path.join("200",uploaded_file)
    br.form.add_file(open(f) ,'text/plain', f)
    br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
    res = br.submit()
    content = res.read()
    with open("200_clean.html", "a") as f:
        f.write(content)

def main():

    for file in os.listdir("200"):
        upload_file(file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but after the execution of the code I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 50, in main
    upload_file(file)
  File "test.py", line 40, in upload_file
    res = br.submit()
  File "/home/suleiman/Desktop/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
    return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/suleiman/Desktop/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/suleiman/Desktop/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error refresh: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
OK
```

could any one help me with this problem  ?

Comment: It looks to me as if it's the site's design that's causing it.

Comment: how do you think I could solve it ?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. I'd assume that it has nout to do with your code, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the mime-type `text/plain` you set. For PDF, this should be `application/pdf`. Your code with this change worked for me when I uploaded a sample PDF.

Change the `br.form.add_file` call to look like this:

```
br.form.add_file(open(f), 'application/pdf', f)
```